# How to calculate a Vector3 position before another object in Unity script?

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting

I have two GameObject:
Obj1 position in world space - `transform.position;`.
Obj1 direction in world space - `transform.TransformDirection;`.
Variable distance - `float distance = 5f;`.

I need to place Obj2 before Obj1 on a fixed distance. How to calculate a Vector3 position for Obj2?

Comment: Have you attempted anything at this point? Please share your current code, so we have a better idea of how you're approaching this problem. Understanding your current approach will make it easier for us to provide a helpful solution.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right, you just want objB to be at a fixed distance to objA, with the relative position being defined by objA's orientation.

This is most easily achieved by having objB be a child of objA. If this is the case, it will move, rotate and even scale together with objA. If the distance and relative direction are constant, just set them up directly in your scene. If they need to be configurable, you require code like this:

```
public class KeepRelativePosition : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float distance = 5f;
    public Vector3 direction = Vector3.forward;

    void Start()
    {
       SetRelativePosition();
    }

    void SetRelativePosition()
    {
        transform.localPosition = direction.normalized * distance;
    }
}
```

If you don't change the predefined values, your object will be 5 units before (->forward direction in parent's local space) the object's parent. But well, your question isn't phrased precicely enough to be sure that's what you wanted.